# get element out of a jinja import

Tags: yaml, jinja2

heyy can someone please help me? i have the following problem.
I have a jinja2 file in this I want to work with data from the value.yaml file. How can I access the name from the yaml file?

test.j2:

```
{% import 'value.yaml' as lol %}
groups:
  -name: {{name}}
```

value.yaml:

```
---
services:
- name: test
```

The result is:

result.yaml

```
groups:
name:
```

So there is missing the test in the yaml

Comment: Jinja won't be able to parse your YAML. What one will usually do is to load the YAML in the script making the template rendering and then pass the value of the parsed YAML to the template.

Comment: I got it bye my self right now, but thank you :)